# Determine the number of bind vars in a string containing SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Given some SQL string, is there a way to find out how any bind variables are inside? E.g.:

```
update t set a = :a /* :a is a bind variable */ 
           , b = ':b' -- :b is not a bind variable, as it's inside a string
```

in a string

```
'update t set a = :a /* :a is a bind variable */ , b = '':b'' -- :b is not a bind variable, as it''s inside a string'
```

Is there some decribe method I can apply on this string in order to learn that there is one bind variable inside?

First I thought about using some regexp_replace on the string in order to remove comments and string contents, but this would be nearly impossible, as colons can appear in comments and strings as shown above, but strings can also contain `/*`, `*/`, and `--`. So I dismissed the idea.

It would require recursion to do this detection properly. But rather then writing a kind of recursive parser query, I hope there is something built-in in Oracle that I can use right away :-)

Comment: Do you mean, simply by looking at the SQL (presented as a string, either in varchar2 or in clob data type)? You need some sort of parser for that. One way (but that doesn't seem to be quite what you are asking) is to run the query, at which point it will appear in `v$sql` (from which you can get the `sql_id`) and in `v$sql_bind_capture` (find your query by `sql_id`) where you can count how many bind variables your SQL statement has.

Comment: @mathguy: Yes, correct, I get the string and want to tell how many bind vars. I thought about opening a ref_syscursor for the query and then maybe get some description, but in order to do that I would have to know the number of bind vars already it seems. I tried without giving it bind var values, which failed of course, but I did see the query in `v$sql`. Unfortunately nothing in `v$sql_bind_capture`, though. Would have been a good solution for me.

Comment: How will you consume this information? An obvious thought (but it may or may not work depending on your actual need) is to copy the SQL string into SQL Developer or Toad and execute it. Before anything is executed, if there are any bind variables, you will be prompted for values, and you will see a list of all bind variables there. (Note however that SQL Developer - I don't know about Toad - seems to have a bug, whereby bind variables are case sensitive!! I just posted a question about this apparent bug on OTN - it was discussed ten years ago with no update since, and no change in behavior.)

Comment: @mathguy. Thank you for your advice. Im writing a function that makes mass updates via `forall`. It gets an update SQL string and a collection of records containing the bind vars (up to ten). So far I have the caller tell me how many bind vars are used in the update SQL string, but I find this redundant and would like to simply investigate the update string - or rather have it investigated :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [REGEXP_COUNT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions135.htm#SQLRF20014) to count bind vars from strings with the comments replaced.

For example:

```
SELECT sqlcode,
REGEXP_COUNT(
 REGEXP_REPLACE(
   REGEXP_REPLACE(
    sqlcode,
    '[/][*].*[*][/]','',1,0,'n'),
    '--.*$','',1,0,'m'),
    '[= ]:\w+', 1, 'i') as TotalBindVars
FROM test;
```

Test on Sql Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/050cbf/3/0)

Comment: Doesn't work: `'select * from dual where id=:id and col1 like :x1;'` has two bind parameters but your query returns one.

Comment: @LukeWoodward now with like

Comment: The bind variables could also be parameters of a function call, i.e. `WHERE start BETWEEN DATE(:a) AND DATE(:b)`. IMO this is the wrong direction

Comment: Also, this would still match code commented out, like `WHERE x = :a /* AND y = :b */`

Comment: Ok, now with first a removal of the comments. And without a check on what's before the bind variable

Comment: Thank you LukStorms. As mentioned, I considered this and then dismissed it. A `/*` introduces a comment. As long as it's not inside a string. `'` introduces a string. As long as it's not inside a comment. One would have to go character by character in order to know whether it is inside a comment or a string or within code. I would be able to write a recursive query or better just a function for this, but I still hope that Oracle offers something out of the box.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I hope someone finds such method. Not sure what you're going to be using it for, but it would be a nice feature. Oh well, I've tried.